# When does the short story "The Recitation of the Most Holy and Harrowing Pilgrimage of Mindy and Also Mork" of the "InCryptid" series take place?

Tags: short-stories, timeline, incryptid, seanan-mcguire

When does the short story "The Recitation of the Most Holy and Harrowing Pilgrimage of Mindy and Also Mork" take place in the chronological order of the InCryptid series? The [InCryptid fandom wiki page of the short story](https://incryptid.fandom.com/wiki/The_Recitation_of_the_Most_Holy_and_Harrowing_Pilgrimage_of_Mindy_and_Also_Mork?oldid=4815) said it takes place between the 25th and epilogue chapters of "Magic for Nothing". However, the book has only *24* chapters, epilogue not included.  Does the story occur between the 24th chapter and the epilogue, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[According to Seanan McGuire](https://twitter.com/seananmcguire/status/1576941079211175936?t=0ywPFcW2nTO3daZGhiRfeQ&s=19):

> Between MAGIC FOR NOTHING and TRICKS FOR FREE.

[image: Image of the author's tweet with the text above]